# Drupal 8 hide meta tag fields in node form

Tags: 8, forms, meta-tags

I am just wandering is there a way to hide some of the input fields in MetaData while creating/editing a node.

For example, I want to hide,

Geographical place name and Geographical position,

that is in MetaData->Advanced, in node form, so that user doesnt have access to it while creating a node.

Anything like hook form alter?

Comment: Have you tried going to Form Display and seeing if you can hide the MetaData there?

Comment: I think hes talking about a subset of tags within the metatag field, so that would not be possible.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Yeah I am talking about the subset of tags

Answer (score 2):

I'll make the assumption you're using the Metatag module (https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag).

Unfortunately, this module doesn't allow fine-grain control of fields through its UI, so the only way I've found to hide these fields is through a form alter.

In this case, I'm modifying all node forms (use whatever hook fits your scenario here). Example, hiding the "advanced" fieldset entirely by disabling access to it, so it's not rendered:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field_metadata']['widget']['0']['advanced']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

I'm sure this can be modified to target more specific nested groups/fields, but should give you a start at least!